# Error converting type SurfaceOrientation to int Xamarin Android Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

I am making a video app in xamarin using visual studio on windows platform.
I have build the app but the video preview is rotated 90 degrees anti-clockwise and having difficulty setting orientation display to rotate 90 degrees clockwise before recording a video. My code is:

```
 namespace XamarinVideoApp
    {
        [Activity(Label = "XamarinVideoApp", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
        public class MainActivity : Activity
        {
            MediaRecorder recorder;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            ...

        }

        protected override void OnDestroy()
        {
            base.OnDestroy();
            if(recorder != null)
            {
               ...
            }
        }

        public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity, int cameraId, Android.Hardware.Camera camera)
        {
            Android.Hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new Android.Hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
            Android.Hardware.Camera.GetCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
            int rotation = (int) activity.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.Rotation;
            int degrees = 0;
            switch(rotation)
            {
                case SurfaceOrientation.Rotation0: /* Shows Error here: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Android.Views.SurfaceOrientation' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) */
                    degrees = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do to remove the error mentioned at the above switch statement?

Comment: I can't find any suggestion regadring how to fix that error like the one in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're casting the `activity.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.Rotation` to an `int`. Simply do the following instead:

```
Android.Hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new
Android.Hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
Android.Hardware.Camera.GetCameraInfo(0, info);
var rotation = activity.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.Rotation;
int degrees = 0;
switch (rotation)
{
    case SurfaceOrientation.Rotation0:
        degrees = 0;
        break;
}
```

Also remember to `break` out of your `switch`.

Additionally, please do note that `Camera.CameraInfo` [was deprecated in API 21](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.CameraInfo.html). You should consider using the [`SensorOrientation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html) for [`Camera2`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html) instead.

This can be done as follows in `Xamarin.Android`:

```
var info = Android.Hardware.Camera2.CameraCharacteristics.SensorOrientation;
```